# How do i run asm files on a mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, assembly, terminal

I'm trying to run a .asm file on a mac (10.7) for a school project. However I can't quite seem to figure out how to actually run it. I know I can run it from the terminal but how?

Or do I have to use xcode to actually run .asm files? Or should I convert the assembly code into another format manually?

For reference the program I'm trying to run is

```
# ************************************************************************
# * Program name : sieve *
# * Description : this program prints all the prime numbers below 1000 *
# ************************************************************************
.bss
NUMBERS: .skip 1000 # memory space for the number table
.text
formatstr: .asciz "%d\n" # format string for number printing
.global main
# ************************************************************************
# * Subroutine : main *
# * Description : application entry point *
# ************************************************************************
   main: movl %esp, %ebp # initialize the base pointer 
   # Initialize the number table:
   movl $0, %eax # initialize 'i' to 0.
   loop1: movb $1, NUMBERS(%eax) # set number table entry 'i' to 'true'
   incl %eax # increment 'i'
   cmpl $1000, %eax # while 'i' < 1000
   jl loop1 # go to start of loop1
   # The sieve algorithm:
   pushl $2 # initialize 'number' to 2 on stack   
   loop2: movl -4(%ebp), %eax # load 'number' into a register
   cmpb $1, NUMBERS(%eax) # compare NUMBERS[number] to '1'
   jne lp2end # if not equal, jump to end of loop 2
   pushl $formatstr # push the format string for printing
   call printf # print the number
   addl $4, %esp # pop the format string
   movl -4(%ebp), %eax # 'multiple' := 'number'
   shl $1, %eax # multiply 'multiple' by 2
   loop3: cmp $1000, %eax # compare 'multiple' to 1000
   jge lp2end # goto end of loop2 if greater/equal
   movb $0, NUMBERS(%eax) # set number table entry to 'false'
   addl -4(%ebp), %eax # add another 'number' to 'multiple'
   jmp loop3 # jump to the beginning of loop 3
   lp2end: movl -4(%ebp), %eax # load 'number' into a register
   incl %eax # increment 'number' by one
   movl %eax, -4(%ebp) # store 'number' on the stack
   cmpl $1000, %eax # compare 'number' to 1000
   jl loop2 # if smaller, repeat loop2
   end: movl $0,(%esp) # push program exit code
   call exit # exit the program
```

Comment: Questions like this are very-very scary.

Comment: [I hope you know how to turn on your spaceship before trying to go to space.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembler)

Answer (score 1):

To build and run this on the command line, i.e. inside the **Terminal** application on a Mac, save the file to `sieve.S` and do something like:

```
$ clang -m32 -g sieve.S -o sieve
$ ./sieve 
2
3
5
<...>
```

I don't know how to build this in Xcode offhand. Just creating an empty project and adding `sieve.S` as a source file might work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the file as a .s file.
2. Go to this URL in a web browser: 
   https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action=Command%20Line%20Tools%20%28OS%20X%20Mountain%20Lion%29
3. Install Xcode Command Line Tools
4. Open Terminal.app (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app).
5. Navigate to the directory you saved your program in using "cd".
6. Execute these commands:

   ```
   $ gcc -o sieve sieve.s
   $./sieve
   ```